# "Non avere che da + infinito" è un'espressione comune?

Tags: phrases

Stavo passando una serata gradevole leggendo un dizionario italiano-inglese e mi sono imbattuto nell'espressione "non avere che da + infinito". Il dizionario dà l'impressione che sia un'espressione comune e di conseguenza ero un po' sorpreso  (anche se non studio l'italiano da molto tempo) del fatto che non l'avessi mai vista prima d'allora.

Sembra essere in certi casi un'alternativa a "bastare":

> non hai che da dirmelo ≈ basta dirmelo
>
> non avrai che da farlo una volta ≈ basterà farlo una volta / dovrai soltanto farlo una volta

Tuttavia, quello che mi interessa di più è la possibilità di adoperare questo costrutto per esprimere "avresti dovuto fare qualcosa", visto che locuzioni di questo genere non mi riescono facilissime da formulare su due piedi.

> non avevi che da dirmelo ≈ avresti dovuto dirmelo
>
> non avevi che da partire prima ≈ saresti dovuto partire prima

Vi sembra che io abbia capito bene l'utilizzo di questa espressione? E si tratta di un modo corrente e naturale di rendere le idee di cui sopra?

Comment: @Gio Thank you very much. I corrected it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sì, l’espressione : *“non hai/avevi/avrai che da”* è comune ma colloquiale.

Da [Sabatini Colletti](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/A/avere_1.shtml): il verbo *avere*:

> in espressioni negative, nel significato  di non dovere far altro che (qui il da è preceduto da che): *non hai che da chiedere*.

L’espressione viene usata principalmente in due circostanze:

1) per dare un suggerimento riguardo qualcosa: *non hai che da chiedere aiuto, e lo avrai*; *non hai che da dire che hai fame, e ci fermiamo a mangiare*.

2) per esprimere un rammarico o un rimprovero: *non avevi che da dire la verità, invece hai mentito*; *non avevi che da chiedere aiuto, invece non l’hai fatto.*

Su [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=avevi%20che%20da%2Chai%20che%20da%2C%20avrai%20che%20da&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cavevi%20che%20da%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chai%20che%20da%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cavrai%20che%20da%3B%2Cc0://) ci sono vari esempi di come viene usata.

Answer (score 6):

Il senso è, come dici, simile a “dovere/aver dovuto [fare qualcosa]”, ma in realtà più a “basta/bastava [fare qualcosa]”. Ha in più il senso che quel qualcosa è anche molto semplice e che ci vuol poco per riuscire a farlo.

“Non hai che da chiederlo”, per esempio, si contrappone a dover implorare, convincere qualcuno, fare vari tentativi etc.: no, basta chiedere e sarà fatto.

È un modo di dire normalissimo, forse lievemente desueto. Eccone un esempio d'autore, da *Il partigiano Johnny* di Beppe Fenoglio:

> Hai fatto malissimo a non credere alla validità dei nostri buoni. Sono garantiti dal popolo italiano, che è poi il tuo popolo. Alla fine della guerra saranno tutti onorati fino all’ultimo centesimo. **Non avevi che da riporlo**, il mio buono, fra tutte le altre luride carte, nel sanctum dei tuoi luridi interessi, ed alla fine trovavi liquidato fino all’ultimo centesimo.

Comment: "Qual qualcosa" sarebbe "quel qualcosa"?

Comment: Giusto, grazie @Charo!